# Disabling a script inside a child component through scripting on parent gameobject

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a script inside a child gameobject , I want to disable it through coding on the parent Object ,help will be much appreciated,thanks.

edit:the script I want to carry out all the actions is not attached to the parent gameobject.

Comment: This is a million-times duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enable Parts/Components in Unity C# with only a game object in the script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31993266/how-do-i-enable-parts-components-in-unity-c-sharp-with-only-a-game-object-in-the)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this code is self commenting ;)

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ScriptAttachedToParent : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void Start () 
    {
        transform.GetChild (0).GetComponent<ScriptAttachedToChild> ().enabled = false;

        // OR
        //transform.Find("ChildGameObject").GetComponent<ScriptAttachedToChild> ().enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Jez since you're rockin' the site, it's worth checking for duplicates first.  You get more points for finding dupes!

Comment: the script is not attached to the parent,hence i can not find the script in GetComponent ,your answer solved half of my problem

Comment: what i did was i found component of type monobehaviour in getcomponent <>,my doubt is what if I have two mono behaviours ,what will it do then

Comment: You should not have more then one same component on one gameObject.