# Disabling a Script attached to a game object in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

I have an update function that will check if something is equal to true and if it is equal to true it will run some code but then I want the whole script to be disabled. Please help, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enable Parts/Components in Unity C# with only a game object in the script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31993266/how-do-i-enable-parts-components-in-unity-c-sharp-with-only-a-game-object-in-the)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use an [enabled](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/scripting/enabling-disabling-components) field. Try following

```
gameObject.GetComponent<EmailSender >().enabled = false;
```

Comment: What do you mean, it doesn't work? What do you expect it to do and what does it do?

Comment: I want it to disable the script so it can't be used anymore.

Comment: @alexo1001 then you need to use `yourGameObject.setActive(false);`

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
public GameObject otherobj;//your other object
public string scr;// your secound script name
void Start () {
    (otherobj. GetComponent(scr) as MonoBehaviour).enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable script component by using the following syntax,

```
GameObject.Find("Cube").GetComponent<MoveObject>().enabled = false;
```

Here I disable the MoveObject script from the object named Cube.